# full calendar draggable

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

**full calendar**: hello, I have a question with jquery full calendar plugin.

When I create a calendar draggable, how to drag events between months?

You can only drag the events of that month.
thanks.

Comment: Please post your sample codes if you have tried some steps.

Answer (score 4):

ok, kinda tricky and not actually a solution. Since you cant display at the same time more than one months, you drag your event at the first days of the next month that are visible, then you navigate to the next month and either move it at the appropriate day or to the next month again